# Effective C++ (3rd edition) Item 4 code layout

Tags: c++, include, effective-c++

In Scott Meyers' *Effective C++: 55 Specific Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs (3rd edition)*, he describes in Item 4 how initialization of non-local static objects defined in different translation units crashes and gives a bunch of example codes.

However, I am confused with the code layout, what should it be?

What I have tried:

- `fileSystem.h`

  ```cpp
  #include <iostream>

  class FileSystem
  {
  public:
      std::size_t numDisks() const;
  };
  ```
- `fileSystem.cpp`

  ```cpp
  #include "fileSystem.h"

  std::size_t FileSystem::numDisks() const
  {
      return 1;
  }

  extern FileSystem tfs;
  ```
- `directory.h`

  ```cpp
  class Directory
  {
  public:
      Directory();
  };
  ```
- `directory.cpp`

  ```cpp
  #include <iostream>
  #include "fileSystem.h"
  #include "directory.h"

  Directory::Directory()
  {
      std::size_t disks = tfs.numDisks();
      std::cout << disks << std::endl;
  }
  Directory tempDir;
  int main()
  {
      return 0;
  }
  ```

And when executing `g++ directory.cpp fileSystem.cpp`, it turns out like this:

```
directory.cpp: In constructor ‘Directory::Directory()’:
directory.cpp:7:25: error: ‘tfs’ was not declared in this scope
    7 |     std::size_t disks = tfs.numDisks();
      |
```

I am a little upset by `#include` stuff in C++, and I hope it would not prevent me from understanding the correct layout of the example code in Effective C++ Item 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `extern FileSystem tfs;` from `fileSystem.cpp` to the header file `fileSystem.h` to be able to compile it.

If it's supposed to be possible to link it, you also need to define it in `fileSystem.cpp`.

**fileSystem.h**

```
extern FileSystem tfs;
```

**fileSystem.cpp**

```
FileSystem tfs;
```

Comment: It works and you remind me that I overlooked Scott's comment about this in the code... but then why does the problem he talks about not happen? Is it amended by new C++ standard?

Comment: @Zebartin I don't actually have that book so it's hard for me to say. I get the impression that he talks about [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof)? If so, it's not guaranteed to fail, but may fail - although in this code there is only _one_ global so I'm not sure how this would fail. If you make "_4 non-local static objects_" as mentioned, the risk of failing increases if you make them depend on eachother and the order of initialization.

Comment: Yes exactly what he talks about. In this code, I want to mess up the initialization order of `tempDir` and `tfs`, which are both non-local static objects according my understanding. I also check out the [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlTrziwQU-w) inside the link you provide, I think the code shown at the beginning of the video looks similar to mine while it goes as expected and mine not. Is there something wrongly set up in my code? Or it is just about random failure, although I have tried many times without failure.

Comment: @Zebartin The code in your question only contains one of these variables. You need a few of them with interdependencies so that the order of initialization becomes important. Fwiw: The common trick to _avoid_ the risk of Static Initialization Order Fiasco is to not have globals at all - or if you do need globals, use _lazy initialization_ so that the objects are created upon first use.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and patience. May I ask the last few questions? Which one is not global object, `tempDir` or `tfs`? Why?

Comment: @Zebartin Oh, sorry, I didn't see `Directory tempDir;` in `directory.cpp` - Yes, then there's is a _risk_ of Static Initialization Order Fiasco in your code. It's not guaranteed though.

Comment: Oh then it is quite weird that I never come across failure, maybe the compiler is too smart, whatever. Thank you again.

Comment: @Zebartin Yeah, if the compiler is able to "see" in which order they need to be initialized, it may initialize them in the proper order. You can increase the risk of seeing the failure by adding  some more classes with this kind of dependency where only one order of initialization can possibly work. Compile each translation unit separately to "hide" as much as possible from the compiler and then link the object files afterwards. The order you link it _may_ have an effect too (not sure).